# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges not working in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

This is how I init my location manager:

```
    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

In iOS6, right after creating it, the delegate is called with my current location:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

However, if the device Im testing is iOS5, this delegate is never called.

What could be the reason?

Comment: The delegate should be called as soon as startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges, as it says in the documentation, and as it works in iOS6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

is new to iOS6, in iOS5 you have to use:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```